# vbox shere folde permission problem

Tags: server

Hi i  have a ubuntu server 23  in vbox i share a folder in automount when try  to open /media/sf_stefano tell  me i not  have permission only  if i open filemanager like root  i can browse the folder , i try to use this command  `sudo chown $USER /media/sf_stefano`
before i run this `sudo chown $USER /media/`  and ok is  change , if  i try to change with `sudo chown $USER /media/sf_stefano`  not  go
my getfacl

```
# file: media/sf_stefano
# owner: root
# group: vboxsf
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```